# How do I build an iPhone Xamarin App without a Mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I'm developing xamarin forms apps. I can generate the APKs and run it on my android devices. But how can I do the same for iPhones without having a mac? Is there a way to build my apps on app center or azure devops where it generates the ipa files?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/ios/

Comment: Thank you. but I write my code in Xamarin.Forms not swift

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/xamarin/ios/

Comment: Can you please mark the answer if it helps you? It will also help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Visual Studio 2019 preview you have the Hot Restart that allow you to deploy with the iTunes to your local iphone/ipad...

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart

Comment: Does this work without any need for a mac? I read through the link and it doesn't specifically say it doesn't need a mac, but it also doesn't say is does.

Comment: @Neil according to [this blog post](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/) it works without a mac

Comment: BTH I tried to not use a Mac, and in the end, I just had to.   You CAN create a basic app, but debugging is really slow,, if you create some custom UI, you can't guarentee it will work properly.   If you can, I'd try and find a old cheap (!!!) Macbook and run VS on that.  It will save you grey hairs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is guidance about how to build Xamarin apps for Android and iOS in azure-devops:

[Build Xamarin apps azure-devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-a-xamarinios-app)

Here is document about how to build Xamarin iOS app in AppCenter:

[Building Xamarin apps for iOS in AppCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/xamarin/ios/)

If you want to build a xamarin.iOS project locally, you must connect to a network-accessible Mac to build Xamarin.iOS applications. Because building native iOS applications requires access to Apple's build tools, which only run on a Mac.

Refer: [Pair to Mac for Xamarin.iOS development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#overview)